# php htaccess redirect to bootstrap file prevents 404 errors with css files etc

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have been working on making own framework and focusing on learning more advanced programming practices, than I learned at college. I use `.htaccess` to redirect all page request to my bootstrap file that loads controllers and themes based on the request URI.

The URL format is `site.com/Controller[/optional/multiple/params]`

The problem is that, lets say, I am trying to include an image or css file and it doesn't exist. In firebug they will not show as 404 errors because of the redirect.

.htacess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

#  Redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I do check and parse the URI and it does forward to the 404 controller and generate a 404 header for the URI requested. However for embeded files like CSS, images etc. they show the same response as the page requested and will not generate 404 errors.

I.E if you go to index.php, index.php will load fine but all the invalid css files will have the same header response as index.php.

Here is the code that loads the controller after the URI is parsed:

```
    //locate
    $file = 'Lume/' . self::$AppPath . 'Controller/' . self::$ControllerName;
    if(!file_exists($file . '.php')){
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        $file='Lume/' . self::$AppPath . 'Controller/_404.php';
    }
    //create
    $controller = str_replace('/', '\\', '/' . $file);
    if(!is_subclass_of($controller, '\Lume\Abstracts\Controller'))
        throw new \Exception('Route::Main The controller must extend from Lume\Abstracts\Controller');
    self::$Controller =& new $controller();
```

Comment: Those two rewriteconds should be preventing rewrites on files/dirs that already exist. Plus your rewriterule isn't passing on your url parameters as query strings, so index.php will never see anything but `/` as the request url.

Comment: All the information you should need to solve this is here (hint: look at `L` and `QSA`): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html - also read up on regex quantifiers here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: @marc there are no query strings. the params look like directories and this is fairly common in MVC frameworks. PHP does see beyond / and i already have that all working. Im just not giving proper 404 errors and wasn't sure if I should fix it in htaccess or in php.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your `.htaccess` file, if the request is **not** for a file or directory **that exists**, then you are asking `index.php` to handle the request. But you are not sending it any query strings or some how passing it data. So you should fix it. While doing that, you can check to see if the query was an invalid controller(you already know it is an invalid file because if it wasn't you'd not have been in index.php). Then you should `header` a `404` error. Because, that way you'd be handling both file not found and contoller not found.

To fix, you can check how other mvc frameworks do it.

Like for example, codeigniter:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

What happens here is, you have access to the request uri as a php variable. So, you can performs checks inside your front controller aka bootstrap for seeing whether the request is valid.

Comment: I have it go to a 404 controller but wasn't sure how to do the 404 error.

Comment: Actually I know how to generate 404 headers but it doesn't work for embedded files like css. I added more info on that in my question.